# sorting data based on values 1st and 2nd column and ouput only uniq values of column 1st and 2nd

Tags: shell, sorting

I have an input file with the following data in it:

```
AUD 100 20
USD 200 30
INR 10  20
AUD 100 30
USD 200 40
EUR 50  60
EUR 50  70
AUD 100 11
USD 200 55
INR 10  35
```

I run:

```
cat filename | sort -u -k1,2
```

It gives me output as follows:

```
AUD 100 20
EUR 50  60
INR 10  20
USD 200 30
```

So what I understand is that `sort -u k1,2` 
sorts the data and gives the output based on unique  combination of values in column #1 and #2.  Now based on this understanding, I run:

```
  cat filename |  sort -u -k1
```

to get the output based on unique values in column #1.  So I expected this output:

```
AUD 100 20
EUR 50  60
INR 10  20
USD 200 30
```

But the actual output was:

```
AUD 100 11
AUD 100 20
AUD 100 30
EUR 50  60
EUR 50  70
INR 10  20
INR 10  35
USD 200 55
USD 200 30
USD 200 40
```

Can someone please explain what's going on with the `sort -u -km,n` option?

Comment: the `m,n` with `-k` signify the starting and ending fields for the `sort` key. With `sort -k1`, the sort key is effective all the fields from `1` to the end, hence the result you see. You need `sort -k1,1`

Comment: Another case of useless cat :)  You can pass the file name to the sort command directly.  No need for cat file | sort.

Comment: Thanks iruvar, but in case I sort the data with sort -u -k1,2   how does sort decide what valued of the third column to print ?

Comment: `-u`implies stable sort therefore it's the first record from each set with identical keys that would be returned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keys field numbers are specified with `-k <start>,<end>`. If you do not specify `<end>` it defaults to the **line end**. So:

```
sort -u -k 1 filename
```

will sort and print unique values based on the **whole line**. If you want to consider only the first key (your expected result) you have to:

```
sort -u -k 1,1 filename
```

P.S. you don't really have to pipe `cat` output to `sort`...